# Android SDK not recognizing debug-able device

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development, and am attempting to run a test application on my actual device. I followed the instructions at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html (and related links), but the Android Debug Bridge (adb) doesn't recognize my connected device.

Some quick background info, I'm running WinXP, developing with Eclipse, with a Motorola Droid running Android 2.1 as my physical device.

An overview of the steps I've taken:

1. Installed the Android SDK, downloading all necessary packages.
2. Enabled USB Debugging on my device.
3. Connected Device via USB, installing the driver from the SDK folder.

I'll stop here (though I continued to setup my application to be debug-able in Eclipse), because I at this point I noticed a problem.

Running "sdk\tools\adb devices" at this point (at least, by my understanding), should list my device as connected. However, running this yields only:

> List of devices attached

My device recognizes that it's connected to a computer in debug mode, and my computer recognizes the device. However, I can't seem to get the sdk to recognize it. I'll leave out the steps I used to setup Eclipse for debugging on a device, as it doesn't seem relevant to the problem. I'll include them if requested.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate some assistance. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11931514/1369566) could help you?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am using HTC OneS. Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. I had the USB debugging enabled. But after plugged in, it doesn't let me deploy. It was recognized as a device: ????... no permissions

What solved my issue is the USB device permission. I found my answer [here](http://dimitar.me/how-to-connect-your-android-phone-to-ubuntu-to-do-developmenttestinginstallations-or-tethering/).

What I did:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

I added this 2 lines in the rule file:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0cec", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SYSFS{product}=="Android Phone", MODE="0666"
```

My device USB vendor:product is "0bb4:0cec". To find it out, use command >lsusb.
Then I unplug/plug my phone. It was recognized.

Comment: Wow thats great. Worked like a charm. But I have a confusion here. It was working fine for more than a year. Yesterday it stopped working. Now I tried this solution and working again. I didn't update any thing on my system at all, neither on my phone. Don't know what exactly happened.

Answer (score 11):

When I had this issue, I figured out that my phone's USB connection was set to media sync mode. When I switched it to mass storage mode, the hello world program loaded right up. I did this by dragging down the USB icon in the top tool bar of the phone's home page.

Comment: Consider improving your answer by simply "Providing an answer", while it might be the right answer, it's better to keep it to the point for other users.

Comment: After a few days trying to figure what could be wrong, I was able to configure my LG in the XE10 device list just using your simple tip.

Answer (score 9):

What usually works for me:

- Unplug device
- Run `./adb wait-for-device` in terminal in your android-sdk platform-tools
- Connect device
- Turn on device

Every time one of my devices doesn't read, this seems to fix the problem.
An alternative is to repeat all those above steps, but don't disconnect the device (i.e. turn it off, run the command, turn it on).

If that doesn't work, another thing that I found that works for the older devices I use (2.1 update 1 and 2.3) is to unplug the usb, turn off usb debugging, turn back on usb debugging, and reconnect.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to get this to work for an Acer A500 with Eclipse on Windows 8 Pro.  I eventually found the solution via [this link](http://www.davinciunltd.com/2011/10/hacking-the-adb-usb-driver-for-acer-a500/comment-page-1/#comment-389).  I also had to follow the instructions at [this link](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/29596-using-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-8/) in order to allow installation of an unsigned driver in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I am using an HTC, so it may be different, but for me i have to sync the device with the pc before it will recognize the phone. When its ready, a notification pops saying that the device is attached for debugging.

Also, you need to mark your app as debuggable if you haven't already done that as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952140/android-how-do-i-mark-my-app-as-debuggable)

Comment: The application is flagged as debugable. I've done all of that.

Comment: sorry, i reread your question and edited my answer. maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the correct driver has been installed successfully (No exclamation mark on the driver icon in device manager), check if the device vendor ID is listed in User\.android\adb_usb.ini.

You device vendor ID can be found at http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

After adding the new vendor ID, reconnect the device and restart adb

For more details see this thread [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x/7136003#7136003)

Answer (score 0):

Kal I had the same situation some months ago, my device was recognized for my computer  but adb doesn't recognize my device is connected, I had to update from the device manager.... hope it helps you!

[adb driver isntalling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974751/samsung-adb-driver-isntalling-error/2975319#2975319)

Comment: Yes, yes I do. I did mention I followed the steps to make my application debug-able. However, that's not relevant, as the problem is the sdk is not detecting my device. It has nothing to do with a specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Motorola's USB driver, as is [described on this thread](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/adb-devices-does-not-show-Droid/m-p/4621).

Comment: The usb driver is installed, yes. However, the device is not recognized by the adb.

Comment: @Kal Zekdor : Perhaps the driver is not being recognized by XP -- with the device plugged in, follow the instructions on http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html to "Update an existing driver", and see if there is any indication of a problem. Perhaps your micro-USB cable is faulty, as I seem to recall running into that once.

Comment: No, the driver is recognized, and windows recognizes the device properly. I'll try on another computer when I get the chance, but for now, I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Having the same issue with the Droid 1 running CM7.

Comment: Nightlive's solution here worked for me: http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/adb-devices-does-not-show-Droid/m-p/10524.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried killing the adb process and starting it back up again? That's worked for me before.

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased a new android phone (LG) and was also having some difficulty.  It seems that my phone would disable debugging on its own whenever I would plug it in to the USB port.

My solution is to plug the phone in, and THEN enable debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When adb stops recognizing my device on Windows, it usually gets fixed with the "adb kill-server / start-server" trick. 
But this time nothing seemed to get it back running,  tried every answer on this thread multiple times (restarting, reconnecting, reinstalling, everything)... 
Then I tried connecting the device to another USB port and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes killing and restarting adb fix this:

in your console:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

(Don't forget to add the sdk's `platform-tools` folder in your `PATH`)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps suggested by Neil Han, but adb still could not recognize my tablet (cheap chinese device - Freelander PD10).

what solved this problem for me was restarting adb as superuser:

```
adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the phone in mass storage mode.  This took me a day and half.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install the USB drivers for the devices from official Android [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html), those are:

1. [Google USB](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. [OEM USB](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Correct if I'm wrong, but cleaning the lint out of the USB port seems to work for some people. Here is a video on how to do it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6p0Eg-yq3A

edit: Seems to have improved connection performance. Device is recognized with the -devices command if the cable it turned upwards and maintained in that position. Connection to the charger is working perfectly so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with my `Sony Experia L`, the problem was my windows firewall, I just change some Inbound and Outbound setting ( Firewall advance setting ) for `abd.exe` ( Emulator ) and problem fixed. Do it and reset your emulator.
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me!

The device driver wasn't installing properly and i had to reboot my computer while holding F8 and turn off forced device signatures.

Answer (score 0):

type on Chrome:

```
chrome://inspect
```

All your connected devices will be listed. If debug session was not enabled, a confirmation dialog should appear in your device. Accept it.

It worked for me.