# How to know programmatically if an app is signed with a Debug or Export certificate?

Tags: java, android, certificate, signed

As the title explains, I would like to know if there's a way (code) to know that the produced app (.apk) is signed with a *Debug* certificate or *Export* certificate? I would like to check this inside my app so that i can enable/disable some features depending on the type of certificate.

I wonder how Google verifies this information at the time when we upload an app in Market through Developer Console?

any suggestion/code would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if APK is signed or "debug build"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085644/how-to-check-if-apk-is-signed-or-debug-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this resource, which describes what you are trying to solve. This page describes how to get information about a keystore in code.

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/detecting-keystore-signature-in-code.html

Comment: 404 - Not Found

Comment: This answer gives an example of how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11535593/2603965

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
final PackageInfo info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
ApplicationUtils.DEBUG_ENABLED = (info.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;
```

to enable/disable debug logging.

Comment: which package contains `ApplicationUtils`?

Comment: `ApplicationUtils` is my own class of static variables/functions that is initialized in `Application.onCreate`.

Comment: The debug flag is automatically set for you when the APK is built with a debug key so you don't need to set it in the manifest.

Comment: @Vinay, you can just use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` now.

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to deploy your app to the Android Market with your *Export* certificate.

The AM will reject your APK if it is not signed with the same certificate you used when you uploaded your first APK.

It looks like you can get info about the Public key from the: javax.security.auth.Subject package (try the getPublicCredentials() method).  I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Yes, i know that we need to update app with the same certificate. But what I'm looking for is the certificate information with in the app, like name, company, organization, isDebug, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The company name is called Android Debug for the debug key.

Run jarsigner -verbose -certs -verify  against the debug and the signed apks. You will see for the debug apk, the CN field is called Android Debug. For your signed apk, it is the name of the key signer.

This is probably how Google and other markets check the key when uploading to the market. Like others said, you will not be able to upload an app signed with a debug key to the market, so I don't know why you would need to check this.

Comment: as i said, i'm not talking about uploading or updating app on market. I just wanted to know these fields with in the code. Is there any possibility?