# How to disable Crashlytics during development

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Is there any simple way to turn Crashlytics Android SDK off while developing ?

I don't want it to send a crash every time I do something stupid

On the other hand I don't want to comment out `Crashlytics.start()` and possibly risk forgetting to uncomment it and commit

Comment: Have you tried just removing your api key from manifest, I don't remember if thats a crash.

Comment: @timmied It crashes. Also commenting the whole line in the `Manifest` crashes the app so this makes the question a little more legit.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Marc from Crashlytics here. Here's a couple of ways to disable Crashlytics while you are doing your debug builds!

1. Use a different android:versionString for debug and release builds and then disable crash reporting from the Crashlytics web dashboard for the debug version.
2. Wrap the call to Crashlytics.start() in an if statement that checks a debug flag. You could use either a custom flag or an approach like the ones proposed here: [How to check if APK is signed or "debug build"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085644/how-to-check-if-apk-is-signed-or-debug-build)

Comment: @marcr How about just using BuildConfig.DEBUG?

Comment: @dannyroa BuildConfig.DEBUG is not a standard flag that works across all build environments. I believe it is set consistently when building with Eclipse & ADT, but not elsewhere.

Comment: @marcr it would be good if we can disable task in gradle for specific flavors/types. this way we can save time on compiling resources

Comment: @marcr I see `Crashlytics.getInstance().setDebugMode(debug)` Does this have any relevance to the original question?

Comment: `BuildConfig.DEBUG` should be used if you are building using Gradle. It will always be generated properly.

Comment: @marcr how about in the latest version of crashlytics (as it seems merged with Fabric), does the library make internal check to `BuildConfig.DEBUG`?

Comment: @akhyar It is not checked automatically, I use: if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());}

Comment: @marcr don't you think Crashlytics should provide methods to enable/disable Crashlytics at rumtime. For example see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168754

Comment: Just in case someone is looking how to implement option #1 for iOS. Run script phase to change version string from `1.0` to `1.0-debug`: `versionString=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}")` and `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $versionString-debug" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`

Comment: The second method is wrong because `Crashlytics.logException(e);` throws an exception in debug builds because Fabric singleton is not initialized.

Comment: Hi Marc I am facing following error related to crashlytics, Can you please check* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':quickRide:packageQrReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'AdharVerificationDynamicFeature' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content.

Answer (score 399):

I found the solution from Crashlytics (with Fabric integration)

Put following code inside your Application class `onCreate()`

```
Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
Fabric.with(this, crashlytics);
```

---

EDIT:

In Crashalitics 2.3 and above, this is deprecated. The correct code is:

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

or

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build());
```

(copied from [Crashlytics deprecated method disabled()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488575/crashlytics-deprecated-method-disabled))

---

EDIT2:

You can also optionally add this to your `buildType` in gradle. This command disables sending the crashlytics mapping file and generating an ID for each build, which speeds up gradle builds of those flavors. (It doesn't disable Crashlytics at run time.) [See Mike B's answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339323/disable-importing-of-crashlytics/28357998#28357998)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
           ....
    }
    debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much nicer to use and will stop your app crashing if you makes calls to Crashlytics in your code, outside of your Application class.

Comment: It works great! Now I can remove all BuildConfig.DEBUG check on all my analytic wrapper methods without fear of crashes.

Comment: It got deprecated in Crashlytics 2.3.0 :(

Comment: @DamianWalczak feel free to send the support team an Email for new answer then. They're responding fast!

Comment: For projects that use new Fabric-powered Crashlytics this should be the marked answer as correct and most straightforward, IMO. P. S.: just was that it's deprecated. @DamianWalczak Any info on what should be used instead?

Comment: the method in **EDIT2** not worked for me, anyone has the same problem?
When I move it into flavors config, Crashlytics will throw `CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException`

Comment: `ext.enableCrashlytics = false`  does not work for me either with 2.5. Actually, it never worked. Even before Fabric.

Comment: I am disabling it at RunTime but Edit 1 is not working for me.

Comment: I have a concern here. Will this enable Answer and Beta ? 
It looks like this should be more correct : CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
    Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Beta(), new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());

Comment: ext.enableCrashlytics = false does not crash if you use this correctly. How to overcome the crash is in Fabrics documentation: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html.

Comment: Fabric say that I must do ", new Crashlytics()" in this case can it be ignored ?

Comment: in addition to this answer, I had to add followings in strings.xml file,
<string name="RANDOM_UUID>5177d524-f7a9-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66</string>
<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">@string/RANDOM_UUID</string>
as per the documentation, this is generated by the plugin but I never used plugin because of personal preference.

Comment: ext.enableCrashlytics = false does not work for me either with 2.6

Comment: If anyone wonders, this solution will not disable Answers and Beta.

Comment: **This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
    install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.**

Comment: @gbero I also had this concern. But when I initialize Crashlytics like mentioned in the answer it seems like answers and beta are initialized correctly `Initializing io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric [Version: 1.4.8.32], with the following kits:
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics [Version: 2.10.1.34]
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta [Version: 1.2.10.27]
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers [Version: 1.4.7.32]
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core [Version: 2.7.0.33]`

Comment: @xialin Any updated method to disable Firebase Crashlytics reporting in BUILD mode

Comment: **this works for me**--> in manifest, `<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />` in gradle, `buildTypes { release {             manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = true}`             `debug {manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = false}`

Answer (score 50):

The chosen answer is not correct any more. Google [changed the integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0) of Crashlytics. My current version is `2.9.1` and the only thing I had to do is, to add `implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'` to my Gradle file. No further things required, nice but this means that Crashlytics is always running.

**Solution 1**

Only compile Crashlytics in release version:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   releaseImplementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1' // update version
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to [additionally configure Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=0) then Solution 1 is not working, since the Crashlytics classes will not be found in Debug Builds. So change the Gradle implementation back to:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1' // update version
```

Then go to your Manifest and add the following `meta-data` tag inside the `application` tag:

```
<application
        android:name="...>

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />

...

</application>
```

Add to your Launch-Activity (only one-time required, not every Activity)

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) { // only enable bug tracking in release version
   Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
```

This will only enable Crashlytics in release versions. Be careful, also check for BuildConfig.DEBUG when you then configure Crashlytics, E.g:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("HASH_ID");
}
```

Comment: This seems clean. Instead of initializing in the primary activity, when not in the Application instance instead?

Comment: They state on the website: `Enable collection for selected users by initializing Crashlytics from one of your app's activities` but I guess it doesn't change much if you initialize Crashlytics in the application. Did you try it? If it works, then I can add it to my answer.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports

Comment: I couldn't get any of the other solutions to work, in order to disable crashlytics at runtime. Solution 1 just worked perfectly - why didn't I think of that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. When I set `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` to false in manifest the crash does not appear on console (I use v2.9.9). So I fixed this by adding separate manifest for debug build with `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled=false` and `true` for release

Answer (score 30):

If you use Gradle just add this to a flavor:

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

Comment: that's only for flavor? what about debug vs. release? I tried to disable for debug but still send the crash

Comment: I think it only works on flavors.
IMO using the flag Austyn and Marcc pointed is the easiest.

Comment: I found out the solution. but not sure if it's compatible for old Crashlytics. it's for the new Crashlytics in Fabric SDK. check my answer below

Comment: This command disables sending the crashlytics mapping file and generating an ID for each build, which speeds up gradle builds of those flavors. (It doesn't disable Crashlytics at run time.) See Mike B's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339323/disable-importing-of-crashlytics/28357998#28357998

Comment: This caused a crash... "`This app relies on Crashlytics.`"

Comment: It caused the same crash for me, so I changed it to disable on Application's onCreate method as suggest on the answer above and it worked.

Answer (score 28):

Check out the latest doc.
https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#gradle-advanced-setup.

Apart from adding `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` in build.grade you need to do,

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
    .build();

// Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

Comment: I tried this way, and still app crashes with `This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at`

Comment: I guess you are missing `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` in build.gradle.

Comment: No, i've added in the debug build type in build.gradle file, it's in `buildTypes -> debug, also i'm applying the plugin via `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`

Comment: I am not sure why this solution was even upvoted 24 times.  Crashes with `This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up`

Answer (score 24):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28723057/2153244) to be the the easiest solution:

```
    release {
        ...
        buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'false'
    }
```

The above lines will create a static boolean field called `enableCrashlytics` in the `BuildConfig` file which you can use to decide whether to initiate `Fabric` or not:

```
    if (BuildConfig.enableCrashlytics)
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

**NOTE:** With this method Fabrics is initialised only in release builds (as indicative in the above code). This means you need to put calls to statics methods in the `Crashlytics` class in an `if` block which checks whether Fabrics has been initialised as shown below.

```
if (Fabric.isInitialized())
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
```

Otherwise the app will crash with `Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()` error when testing on the emulator.

Answer (score 24):

**2019 Answer**

I've been trying to only enable Crashlytics in release and disable in debug for 2 hours, checking the Firebase console to see if the Exceptions where uploaded or not.

There are 2 possible ways to do this.

### OPTION 1

It works, but if you call any `Crashlytics` method on debug builds the app will *crash*.

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    <application
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsEnabled}" />
```

### OPTION 2

An alternative if that allows you to call `Crashlytics` methods without checking `BuildConfig.DEBUG` first. With this setup you can safely call methods like `Crashlytics.logException()` - they simply do nothing in debug builds. I don't see the reports being uploaded in debug.

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    <application
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
```

Application onCreate()

```
val crashlytics = Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
    .build()
Fabric.with(this, crashlytics)
```

Comment: I think `android:value="false"` has to be changed to `android:value="${enableCrashlytics}"`. Isnt it?

Comment: Another advantage with Option #2 is that you start with analytics collection initially disabled, and then can ask the user first it it's OK to track their app usage (think GDPR). Then you'd only do the Fabric.with call if the user consented to tracking.

Comment: The only downside of option #2, is that it still creates debug versions in Firebase dashboard, even though no crashes will be shown there (since they are disabled). This makes two problems - first, it makes harder to find release versions; second - Firebase dashboard shows [only last 100 versions](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/crashlytics-versions.html) - which might prevent you from seeing crashes in some old versions. In Fabric dashboard you could disable a particular version, [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59963555/1233652) in Firebase's dashboard.

Answer (score 15):

Use this in `MyApplication#onCreate()`

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) Crashlytics.start(this);
```

**EDIT**
If you upgraded to Fabric, use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191197/116938) instead.

Comment: BuildConfig.DEBUG isn't always set properly. Relying on it to enable/disable Crashlytics caused quite a few problems for me while using IntelliJ.

Comment: What build tools are you using? Gradle will ALWAYS set that value. It was a problem a year ago, but the new build tools are much better.

Comment: I'm on v0.9.+ of the Gradle plugin for IntelliJ and v1.11 for Gradle itself.

Comment: I have not seen any issues in any of my apps. `BuildConfig` is generated by a Gradle task, which is guaranteed to run. I also use `buildConfigField` to set custom fields and those always work. http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio045released also suggests that you use `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

Comment: As an idealist I sure would like to be able to use it as it would simplify the not-quite-automated build process for the small company I work for. It's just that we released into production a build that was depending on that flag and Crashlytics never saw it go live. After we went back to toggling it manually Crashlytics saw it immediately.

Comment: Given your experience contradicts what the actual documentation says, I am going to continue using the flag. I've seen plenty of other open source applications using it also.

Answer (score 11):

Another simple solution that I like, because it doesn't require different manifest files:

Step 1 - define manifest placeholders in build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlytics:"true"]
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlytics:"false"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Step 2 - use them in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="${crashlytics}" />
```

Answer (score 10):

As per google use this code for disable Crashlytics and it will also improve build process.

[image]

reference-https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build

Comment: Unfortunately, that documentation is deprecated, and the flags that you are referencing are not supported anymore, check it here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?hl=da&platform=android

Answer (score 10):

**2022 answer using FirebaseCrashlytics.**

**There are two cases:**

1. If you want to disable Crashlytics data collection for all app runs (such as disabling Crashlytics in debug mode), then you need to disable it the manifest file by setting the flag `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` to `false`

build.gradle (:app)

```
// Next two flags to enable/disable Crashlytics
def enableCrashlyticsInDebugBuild = false
def enableCrashlyticsInReleaseBuild = true


android {
  buildTypes {

        release {
                manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled:"${enableCrashlyticsInReleaseBuild}"]
        }

        debug {
                manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled:"${enableCrashlyticsInDebugBuild}"]
        }
  }
}
```

Then in the manifest file add this under the `application` tag.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsEnabled}" />
```

2. If you want to disable Crashlytics for some users when they opt out from data collection.

To handle that you should use the method `setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled`.

Kotlin API (The Java API is similar):

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
```

When set to false, the new value does not apply until the next run of the app.

References:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics#setcrashlyticscollectionenabled

Comment: This worked for me. Before, I had been using `extra["enableCrashlytics"] = false` which wasn't working.

Comment: Please correct to manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsEnabled"] = false/true. Also using a variable doesn't adds value to the solution in this concrete case.

Comment: @David Adding the flag give the developer more control to enable/disable without going into details internally. The variable is descriptive. Change it directly and go. N need to check and read the code to know where to update.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to capture all crashes (for debug and release builds) but want to separate them in the Crashlytics Dashboard, you can add this line of code to build.gradle:

```
debug {
    versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
}
```

For example, if your app's versionName is 1.0.0, your release builds will be tagged as 1.0.0 while debug builds will be 1.0.0-DEBUG

Comment: This is it? No need to do flavors?

Answer (score 6):

Notice that you can also disable the annoying uploading of symbols in debug build:

```
def crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsDebug = "crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsDebug"
def crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug = "crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug"
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsDebug.equals(task.name) ||
            crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug.equals(task.name)) {

        println "Disabling $task.name."
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Just put it into the `build.gradle` of your application module.

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty of good answers here, but for my testing I use debug builds for in-house betas and out-of-the-lab testing where crash logs are still very useful and I would still like to report them. Like the OP, all I wanted was to disable them during active development where I am often causing and quickly resolving crashes.

Rather than remove ALL debug crashes you can choose to only disable the reports while a device is connected to your development machine with the following code.

```
if (!Debug.isDebuggerConnected()) {
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
```

Comment: It's wrong. I log non-fatal exceptions in my code using `Crashlytics.logException(e)` and this statement throws an exception in debug builds because Fabric singleton is not initialized. If you use Crashlytics then always initialize Fabric singleton. See [fahmy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30837601/1429387).

Answer (score 6):

There are two options in order to disable Firebase Crashlytics for the following version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0:

1. Add meta-tag to app's Manifest

`<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />`

OR

2. Configure directly in the app (keep in mind when set to false, the new value does not apply until the next run of the app)

`FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 6):

Create a class that extends from **Application** if you don't already have one in your application.

Then do the following :

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application { // extend from MultidexApplication if multidex is required by your application 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        /*
         *  Crashlytics is enabled by default,
         *  Disable it for debug builds & USB Debugging
         * */

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){ 
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
        }
  }
}
```

and don't forget to add the class in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ........>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that none of the solutions does work for the latest crashlytics sdk. (I'm using 2.9.0)

You can't disable it by code since it compiles into your project and runs before even a call onCreate of your application. So other solution is simple - don't compile crashlytics when not needed.
Replace the 'compile' call with 'releaseCompile' within build.gradle file.

```
 releaseCompile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Updated answer:
Disable crashlytics from the gradle config to benefit from improved build speeds.

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
}
```

or kotlin kts:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            extra["enableCrashlytics"] = false
        }
    }
}
```

and then programatically:

```kotlin
// Initializes Fabric for builds that don't use the debug build type.
Crashlytics.Builder()
        .core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
        .build()
        .also { crashlyticsKit ->
            Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit)
        }
```

You can also keep using crashlytics on debug builds but still benefit from improvements in build speed by preventing crashlytics from generating a new ID for each build:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            extra["alwaysUpdateBuildId"] = false
        }
    }
}
```

or groovy:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
    }
}
```

Check the documentation link below:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#disable_crashlytics

Answer (score 3):

Up to date easiest version when using Gradle to build:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
```

It uses the new Built-In Syntax from Fabric for Crashlytics and works automatically with the a Gradle build.

Answer (score 3):

A strange problem that I encountered: I followed [xialin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264461/xialin)'s answer (which also appears on the official website) and it didn't work. Turned out that I was referencing `BuildConfig` in Fabric's package which also contains a static DEBUG variable that was set to false even in debug mode.

So, if you follow the aforementioned solution and you still get debug reports, make sure that you're referencing this:

```
import com.yourpackagename.BuildConfig;
```

And not this:

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.BuildConfig;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **dedicated manifest file** for debug mode (works for me with Crashlytics 2.9.7):

Create the file `app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following:

```
<application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false"/>

</application>
```

Note that this meta-data element must be put into debug/AndroidManifest.xml **only**, and not into the regular AndroidManifest.xml

The solution which uses `CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()` did not work for me, and I found out that crashlytics is initialized by the CrashlyticsInitProvider before Application.onCreate() is called or an any activity is started, which means that manually initializing fabric in the application or an activity has no effect because fabric is already initialized.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about `BuildConfig.DEBUG` not being set up correctly, use `ApplicationInfo` instead:

```
boolean isDebug = ( mAppContext.getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) != 0;
Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder().disabled( isDebug ).build();
Fabric.with( uIContext, crashlytics );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flavors or build configs. Use a separate build identifier for dev build and all your crashes will keep going to a separate app. Can come handy in case of sharing the build with peers or using it without a debugger. Something like this -

```
    productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "io.yourapp.developement"
    }
    staging {
        applicationId "io.yourapp.staging"
    }

    production {
        applicationId "io.yourapp.app"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a debuggable release build, here's the way:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        debuggable true //-> debuggable release build
        minifyEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled false
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'BUILD_TYPE_DEBUG', 'false'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'BUILD_TYPE_DEBUG', 'true'
    }
}
```

When you set `debuggable true` your BuildConfig.DEBUG will initialized with true, that's why I added that variable in BuildConfig class.

Init Fabric:

```
Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder()
            // disable crash reporting in debug build types with custom build type variable
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE_DEBUG).build())
            .build();

    final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(crashlytics)
            //enable debugging with debuggable flag in build type 
            .debuggable(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();

    // Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
    Fabric.with(fabric);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `ext.enableCrashlytics` and `ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId` since they don't seem to be referenced anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jules It's in the docs https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html

Comment: BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE_DEBUG is redundant, BuildConfig.DEBUG can be used for getting same value

Comment: @AntonisRadz Because I needed a debuggable release build

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Post Fabric Answer**

Paste the code below in your Application class and call the method `setCrashlyticsState` from your application onCreate. You may optionally add your test device Ids to the `debugDevices` HashSet too so that your personal devices can be ignored, even when building in release mode.

Note. The device id returned by `Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);` is not **guaranteed** to be unique or constant (It can change on a factory reset or manually on a rooted device). But it should be good enough.

```
private final HashSet<String> debugDevices = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("6a3d5c2bae3fd32c"));

private boolean isDebugDevice(String deviceId) {
    return debugDevices.contains(deviceId);
}

private void setCrashlyticsState() {
    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG || isDebugDevice(deviceId)) {
        Log.v("DeviceId", deviceId);
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Check that BuildConfig. is looking at the correct BuildConfig class. There are often several options and the wrong one could be dragged in.

Comment: To add to this answer, most developers will be just interested by 
 `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
}`

Answer (score 1):

We can use fabric's isDebuggable() method.

```
import static io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.isDebuggable;

if(! isDebuggable()){
    // set Crashlytics ... 
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: In build.grade

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashlytic:false]
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashlytic:true]
        }
    }
```

Step 2: In manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${enableCrashlytic}" />
```

Step 3: In Application or first Activity

```
private void setupCrashReport() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) return;
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
```

I am not sure if the step 3 is necessary, but to make sure the release version should work without crash. source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#enable_opt-in_reporting

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you only want to do it on your IDE is to logout of the plugin. Apparently it will stop sending reports while you're generating builds without logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
    releaseCompile  'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
```

and in buildTypes:

```
debug {
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}
```

Comment: How about usages of Crashlytics in code? It will give you compilation errors.

Comment: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add this to your app’s build.gradle:

   ```
   android {
       buildTypes {
           debug {
             // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
             ext.enableCrashlytics = false
             ...
   ```
2. Disable the Crashlytics kit at runtime. Otherwise, the Crashlytics kit will throw the error:

   ```
   // Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
   // Add These lines in your app Application class onCreate method

   Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
       .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
       .build();

   // Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
   Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
   ```
3. In AndroidManifest.xml, add

   ```
   <meta-data
   android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
   android:value="false" />
   ```

Answer (score -9):

This is silly answer, I know
Just comment out `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`, work on that and uncomment it when you want to release it.