# Crashlytics control when crash is reported

Tags: crashlytics

Is there a way to enable or disable sending crash report depending on a particular criteria. For example if want to send the crash report only if the device is connected to wifi and not through cellular network

Or if we want to send the report at a later time triggered by a user click a button.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there's no way to do this via a criteria. You can either turn on/off crashing on the Crashlytics website. As for your second question this is the only way for now: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92530-can-i-toggle-whether-or-not-a-user-needs-to-give-p

I was talking a while back with one of the members of their team and they said they may look into turning off/on the ability to collect crashes with a check box or something. So we'll see if that happens in the future.   :)

Edit: actually see if something like this suits your needs
[How to disable Crashlytics while developing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986753/how-to-disable-crashlytics-while-developing/16990788#16990788)