# Disable importing of Crashlytics

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I just recently integrated Crashlytics into my App. But I am having a "problem": It's always enabled.

On their page (and in various stackoverflow threads) it's said to turn it off I have to include `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` into my build.gradle.
So my buildTypes look like the following:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-DEV"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false //TODO:Switch to true and add Proguard config to release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
    }
```

But every time I run the debug buildType the application works without any crashes, i.e. `Crashlytics.start(this)` works without a crash even though I thought that it wouldn't even be compiled into the app with `enableCrashlytics = false` (strange "problem" to report, I know).

I want to understand why the app doesn't crash (to further improve my understanding of using the build.gradle file). 
And I want to understand why I can't disable Crashlytics with the gradle directive proposed by Crashlytics themselves. I know I can get rid of Crashlytics by simply not starting it (no call to `Crashlytics.start(this)`) but then the directive `enableCrashlytics` would be useless, right?

Am I missing something?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve i tried to understand your question but couldn't, could you simplify what is your question?

Comment: I refined my question

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics here.

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

disables sending a mapping file to our backend or generating an ID for your build, which speeds up gradle builds of those flavors.

If you want to disable Crashlytics for debug builds, then the answers from [this SO question should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986753/how-to-disable-crashlytics-while-developing)

Comment: In my case, it does not work because my app crashes `This app relies on Crashlytics`. Release builds work fine when crashlytics is enabled

Comment: Does it also not work if you use the instructions in the SO link?

Comment: It's an old topic and I remember I deleted the debug application from crashlytics but I'm not sure that was the solution. In fact, I hope acquisition of crashlytics by google will facilitate our lives :)