# Crashlytics deprecated method disabled()

Tags: android, crashlytics

When using Crashlytics + Fabric for Android there is a really easy way to enable and disable crash reporting. I use it so during development and testing there aren't a ton of crashes alerting everyone.

```
Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder().disabled(true).build();
```

The disabled(boolean) method is now deprecated. Does anyone know what the replacement is for disabling and enabling crashlytics programmatically?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

Here's what you want to use depending on your preference:

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

or

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build());
```

See [`CrashlyticsCore.Builder#disabled` documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics-core/2.3.3/com/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore.Builder.html#disabled(boolean)).

Comment: Perfect! I wish there was better documentation where I could have found this.

Comment: Mike , does the second line have to read this way: Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build(), new Crashlytics());

If not then I keep receiving the following error in the stacktrace when the app launches

E/Fabric﹕ Error performing auto configuration.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented

Comment: @jmrmb80 try using Crashytics 2.3.0 and let me know if that works!

Comment: The Android Studio plugin keeps correcting it?

Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build());

>>

Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build(), new Crashlytics());

Comment: Is this redundant if we disable crashlytics in gradle via [the documentation](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202938-gradle) that suggests adding `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` to the flavor?

Comment: @gmale that command disables Crashlytics from being built as part of your Gradle build flow. It doesn't disable Crashlytics at run time. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339323/disable-importing-of-crashlytics/28357998#28357998

Comment: @MikeB how can we disable it at runtime?

Comment: Above code is not working, i am using `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.2@aar`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal you'd want to use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992076/disable-crashlytics-answers-based-on-user-setting

Comment: @MikeBonnell, will this code disable it if it has already been enabled before? From what I see, 'Fabric.with()' returns a singleton that doesn't change if it has already been initialized.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena There isn't a "kill" switch for the SDK currently. Once enabled, Crashlytics continues to run until a session ends. You would need to restart the app to disable it once more.

Comment: @MikeBonnell i did what you mentioned above. But I think its not working. I am still getting `Crashlytics report upload complete: <alphanumeric>.cls`

Comment: @uday There have been many different comments, so it's a bit hard to follow along. Can you share more information about what you're using and what's not working?

Comment: This is still sending crash reports on debug builds. Marc's answer might be convenient for this case but the project i am working on previous developer used crashlytics.logException method in a lot of places. I wish disabled method actually stop sending crash reports on debug builds.

Comment: @MikeBonnell There isn't a "kill" switch for the SDK currently. Once enabled, Crashlytics continues to run until a session ends. You would need to restart the app to disable it once more. Its an older comment, Is this Statement valid even now ? We can't Disable Fabric , if it is already enabled in a single session ?

Comment: Correct, there have been no changes to the SDK on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Fabric Crashlytics SDK is now deprecated and FirebaseCrashlytics should be used

```
// Explicit initialization of Crashlytics is no longer required.
// OPTIONAL: If crash reporting has been explicitly disabled previously, add:
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG);
```

See the [migration documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#firebaseno_longer_works_with_the_fabric_sdk)