# Crashlytics: All methods appear to be deprecated?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm trying to add custom keys to my crash reports as described here:

http://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-keys

However, all the methods appear to be deprecated:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488575/crashlytics-deprecated-method-disabled/30489601#30489601), the documentation is outdated.

You are supposed to use:

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().core.setXYZ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is 2.3.2 and the documentation indicates to use CrashlyticsCore.getInstance() instead of Crashlytics directly to set custom keys or log.

http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics/2.3.2/

** UPDATED **

The documentation page has been updated: https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/enhancing-crash-reports

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().core
```

Comment: Actually the latest is 2.3.2.   :)