# Proper way to initialize Fabric.io for debugging/release

Tags: android, crashlytics, fabric.io

Just a quick question about Crashlytics from Fabric.io:

To disable it in debug, should we still use:

```
 Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
        Fabric.with(this, crashlytics);
```

Or does Fabric handle the debug/release difference and should we just use:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

The disabled method is depricated and if you use the Fabric plugin in Android Studio, it always changes the crashlytics instance to `new Crashlytics()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the new **2.3.+** version you should use somenthing like this:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                    .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    .build())
            .build());
```

Comment: How to disable Answers? similar kind of above, I tried but it is not able to disable for Debug Build

Comment: @NaveenKumarM were u able to disable Answers for Debug builds

Comment: Yes @ismailqbal use this code
if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Fabric.Builder.debuggable(boolean)
```

Java Doc API [Crashlytics](http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics/2.2.4/com/crashlytics/android/Crashlytics.html)

> setDebugMode(boolean debug)
>   Deprecated. 
>   use Fabric.Builder.debuggable(boolean) instead

**UPDATED**

For more info visit [SO - CrashLytics Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489601/2032561)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have a debug version of Application: https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/stetho-for-android-debug-builds-only/

Basically, you'd need to have a debug version of your `Application` in the `debug` folder, with a debuggable version of Fabric, alongside with the manifest file, that is going to address your DebugApp:

```
<manifest
    package="com.mycompany"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        tools:replace="android:name"
        android:name=".DebugApp"/>

</manifest>
```