# Disable Crashlytics/Answers based on user setting

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am adding a new preference on my app, to allow the user to opt out of analytics reports. I am using in my app Crashlytics and Answers by Fabric.

I have this code within onCreate:

```
if (PreferenceHelper.getAllowAnalytics(context)) {
            Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        } else {
            //no crash or answers to be sent
        }
}
```

and each time I want to send an event I do it like this:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("test event"));
```

This works well, when the user allows it.
How should I handle the `else` when the user decides not to allow analytic?

Comment: You could wrap all of your calls to Answers.getInstance in a new class that checks your preference and does nothing if it's not enabled?

IE: Instead of Answers.getInstance().logCustom()

WrappedAnswers.getInstance().logCustom().

And wrapped answers would do your if/else check in logCustom()

Comment: @natez0r please make this as an answers as this is the path I am using for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap all of your calls to Answers.getInstance in a new class that checks your preference and does nothing if it's not enabled? IE: Instead of Answers.getInstance().logCustom() WrappedAnswers.getInstance().logCustom(). And wrapped answers would do your if/else check in logCustom()

Answer (score 2):

Could do something like this without using an if/else:

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!PreferenceHelper.getAllowAnalytics(context)).build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

This way if your getAllowAnalytics method returns false, then Fabric/Crashlytics will be disabled, otherwise it will be enabled.

Comment: This will take care of Crashlytics,  but how about Answers?

Comment: I believe you need Crashlytics enabled to use Answers. If Crashlytics is disabled I don't believe Answers will work.