# Disable Crashlytics in Android library project for debug

Tags: android, module, crashlytics

I have a project with multiple modules. The common code of the modules is in a library module. The problem is that we added recently Crashlytics to our project (in the library module), and we keep receiving error reports even when we are in Debug mode.

I searched on the internet and I found out that a library is always seen as a Release mode. Now my question is, is there a way to disable Crashlytics in my case?

Comment: Check out stackoverflow.com/questions/35312743 if you want to remove the "release only" restriction on your library module. I ran into the same issue on my project.

Answer (score 12):

In my app (a single module, multiple flavors), I detect the flavor, and only initialize Crashlytics in the flavors that I want.

In my case, I add a variable to the flavor in build.gradle , like so:

```
productFlavors {
        Dev { // i.e. gradlew assembleDevDebug
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'false'
        }

        Qa { // i.e. gradlew assembleQaDebug
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
        }
}
```

Then, in my Application class, I conditionally start Crashlytics:

```
if(BuildConfig.enableCrashlytics == true) {
   Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
```

Comment: I've seen this answer at several places on stack, but it causes a crash anywhere I call Crashlytics.log(). Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @jwBurnside I recognize this is years late, but will state this for future readers: yes, calling Crashlytics.log() without first calling Fabric.with() WILL crash the app, so I do not advise the approach of saying "we'll only initialize Crashlytics in release builds".

Comment: This is a good point. I keep track (in my Application class) of whether Crashlytics has been initialized or not, and only call Crashlytics.log() if it has been. Actually, I use Timber for logging, and have different logging "Trees" for dev and prod. The prod tree calls Crashlytics.log() when logging an error, and the dev log does not.

Comment: I disable Crashlytics in this manner 
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you enable Crashlytics/Fabric from your main module (which is recognised as being in debug), just conditionally initialise it so it does not activate in Debug mode.

e.g

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I now I should check if it is in debug mode or not, but this is the problem. A library module is always seen as in release.

Comment: But as I said, you are running the above code from your main app not from your library.