# Disable Fabric AnswersKit when user opts out of analytics reporting

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar version of crashlytics and I want to disable Answers automatic reporting when user opts out of analytics using our app setting. I noticed that when crashlytics is disabled using the below code, top level metrics like active users, sessions etc., are still being reported. This post [How to disable Crashlytics Answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964038/how-to-disable-crashlytics-answers/31990623) explains how to disable answers events and custom events when user opts out, but I didn't understand how we can disable automatic metrics. Can anyone please suggest if there is a way to disable Answers kit completely at runtime?

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
          .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(true).build())
          .build();
  Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If Answers is disabled using the link you sent, all Answers data is not collected. However, data for non-opted out users would still be collected.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to disable crashlytics/answers at run time? When user turns off the setting for sending data to fabric, I want to disable crashlytics/answers immediately. I'm not able to find a way to achieve this. Does fabric provide any other api for disabling at run time? If not, the only way I see is to kill the app and restart it with Crashlytics disabled using the above code.

Comment: There is not a run time kill switch. You need to restart the app currently.