# How to clear Crashlytics, Answers, other Kits from Fabric at runtime in Android

Tags: android, crashlytics

We are using the following code to initialize various Fabric Kits at startup:

```
Fabric.with(appContext, new Crashlytics(), new Answers());
```

If at runtime, I need to remove a particular kit due to configuration changes related to the data collection restrictions of the region where the App is deployed, I can issue another **Fabric.with()** call with just the Kits that are allowed.

How can I completely remove ALL of the Kits at runtime, after some had been previously configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mike Bonnell from Fabric there's currently no way right now to disable at runtime, only when the app starts.

[Disable Fabric AnswersKit when user opts out of analytics reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214455/disable-fabric-answerskit-when-user-opts-out-of-analytics-reporting)