# How to Disable Crashlytics/Fabric at Runtime when User Changes Preferences

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.2@aar` version of crashlytics and i disable crash reporting if user opt out.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191197/1773155) solution but still it is not working, crash reports are still being sent to Fabric.

I am doing it as:

```
Preference errorReportingEnabled = findPreference(MatlistanPrefs.BUGREPORTS_SEND_AUTOMATICALLY);
    errorReportingEnabled.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

            Boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;

            Fabric.with(DataCollectionSettingsActivity.this, new Crashlytics.Builder().
                    core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!value).build())
                    .build());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Is there any working solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Fabric on initialization creates a singleton instance and returns same instance whenever you call `Fabric.with(...)`. So, your code inside `onPreferenceChange`has no effect on Fabric class.

The only solution to this problem can be if library itself provide methods for enabling or disabling crashlytics. So, **up-till** now (`crashlytics:2.5.2`) there is **no solution** to enable/disable crashlytics at run-time. You have to do it at startup like this:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
    .disabled(true).build()).build());
```