# How to disable Fabric when running tests

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, google-fabric

How can I disable Fabric: Crashlytics and Answer when running tests?

Is there any other way to disable Crashlytics during the test instead of putting this code before every test?

```kotlin
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AcceptanceTest {
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
          val crashlyticsKit = Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build()
          Fabric.with(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), crashlyticsKit)
    }

}
```

and avoiding to put a global boolean like `IS_TEST_MODE`

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986753/how-to-disable-crashlytics-while-developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a better and cleaner way to disable and manage Fabric.

In my application I use `slf4j-api`, a log API used a lot in web development. With this API you can create appender, so I decided to create a Fabric Appender and use this appender only when the app run.

## How to

### Install `slf4j` with `Logback`

#### Set your `build.gradle`

```gradle
dependencies {
    ...
    // Log
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
}
```

#### Add `src/main/assets/logback.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="FABRIC" class="path/to/your/FabricAppender" />
    <appender name="LOGCAT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <tagEncoder>
            <pattern>%logger{0}</pattern>
        </tagEncoder>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[PUP] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="LOGCAT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FABRIC" />
</root>
```

By default `Logback` has a customize appender working with `Logback`. You can comment the `FABRIC` part we will be explain later.

#### Add `src/androidTest/assets/logback.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="LOGCAT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <tagEncoder>
            <pattern>%logger{0}</pattern>
        </tagEncoder>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[PUP] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGCAT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You don't want to have Fabric appender here! because you want your instrumented test running only with `Logcat`

#### Use `Logback`

Now you can easily log using the powerful API of `slf4j` like below

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)!! // Call your logger in each class with this line

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        log.info("Activity start")
        // ...
    } }
```

### Set Fabric for `Logback`

#### Create in your project `FabricAppender.kt`

```kotlin
package your.package.log

import android.content.Context
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
import ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.CustomEvent
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric

class FabricAppender : UnsynchronizedAppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>() {
    companion object {
        private var isFabricInit = false

        fun init(context: Context) {
            Fabric.with(context, Crashlytics(), Answers())
            isFabricInit = true
        }
    }

    override fun append(event: ILoggingEvent) {
        if (isFabricInit.not()) return
        when (event.level.levelInt) {
            Level.ERROR_INT -> {
                val throwable = (event.throwableProxy as ThrowableProxy).throwable
                if (throwable != null) {
                    Crashlytics.logException(throwable)
                } else {
                    Crashlytics.log(event.message.replace(": {}", ""))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This appender will send exception to `Crashlytics` every time you call `log.error("Something wrong happen!!")`. As you can see, you can fully customized the appender.

#### Init the appender when application start

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)!! // Call your logger in each class with this line

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        FabricAppender.init(this) // Init before the first log

        log.info("Activity start")
        // ...
    } }
```

## Finally

Now your fabric will be totally isolated to your code by using the `slf4j` API, and will be not use during your instrumented test yataaa!!! You can find other appender on internet (send to ELK, file, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use flavors.

By default, you have flavor called `main`, where you should put all of base your code, assets and manifests, that are used in development, testing and production. You can easily create a new flavor by adding your flavor name under `buildTypes { ... }` in your module's build.gradle file. This lets you split dependencies and easily remove anything that you do not want or even need in your release builds. You can read more about flavors [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html). This way, you'll be able to separate core code in main flavor and add crashlytics in your release builds only.

For example, in your main flavor:

```
open class BaseApplication : Application()
{ 
    fun onCreate()
    {
       [common code between flavors]
    }
}
```

Then in your release flavor

```
open class MainApplication : BaseApplication()
{
    fun onCreate()
    {
      [initialize crashlytics]
    }
}
```

And in your other flavors

```
open class MainApplication : BaseApplication()
```

Note: Use `MainApplication` instead of `BaseApplication` in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling it on every Espresso test, we avoid enabling it when running the debug build type.

So, in your `Application` class, build Crashlytics and Answers like this:

```java
CrashlyticsCore crashlyticsCore = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
    .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .build();

Fabric.with(this,
    new Crashlytics.Builder().core(crashlyticsCore).build(),
    new Answers());
}
```