# How do I detect if I am in release or debug mode?

Tags: android, android-build-type

How can I detect in my code that I am in Release mode or Debug mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 



}
```

This Is Working For Me

Answer (score 952):

The simplest, and best long-term solution, is to use `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. This is a `boolean` value that will be `true` for a debug build, `false` otherwise:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something for a debug build
}
```

There have been reports that this value is not 100% reliable from Eclipse-based builds, though I personally have not encountered a problem, so I cannot say how much of an issue it really is.

If you are using Android Studio, or if you are using Gradle from the command line, you can add your own stuff to `BuildConfig` or otherwise tweak the `debug` and `release` build types to help distinguish these situations at runtime.

The solution from Illegal Argument is based on the value of the `android:debuggable` flag in the manifest. If that is how you wish to distinguish a "debug" build from a "release" build, then by definition, that's the best solution. However, bear in mind that going forward, the `debuggable` flag is really an independent concept from what Gradle/Android Studio consider a "debug" build to be. Any build type can elect to set the `debuggable` flag to whatever value that makes sense for that developer and for that build type.

Comment: `BuildConfig` is located in your app's package, e.g. `import com.mycompany.myapp.BuildConfig;`

Comment: due to a bug in AndroiStudio this does not work anymore, it is always false, even in DEBUG mode

Comment: @user387184: In Android Studio 1.2.2, I get `public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");` for a debug build. While that is a bizarre way to set `DEBUG` to `true`, it should work. If you are seeing this in one of the 1.3.0 test releases, or if you have a reproducible test case for 1.2.2, please [file an issue](http://b.android.com). I do not see any outstanding issues reporting this problem.

Comment: I am using v1.2.2 and BuildConfig.DEBUG is always false, then I tried the suggestion below which works for me - I will try yours as well - many thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, approach mentioned by Illegal Argument does work.

Comment: In Android Studio 1.3 `BuildConfig.DEBUG` can be `true`

Comment: I have upgraded to AS-1.3 stable version but when I used `BuildConfig.DEBUG` in `MyApplication` class it still returned false.

Comment: As it turns out, this won't work when using a library (always returns true) : http://stackoverflow.com/q/20176284/878126 . Wonder what's the best alternative

Comment: Works fine on AndroidStudio 2.2.3

Comment: In AndroidStudio, where can I switch between DEBUG and RELEASE?

Comment: @digorydoo: See the Build Variants tool, default docked on the left edge of the IDE.

Comment: This is always false for me, have never created a release build.. In every android studio version

Comment: @behelit: Then perhaps ask a separate Stack Overflow question, seeking help for your issue, with a [mcve].

Comment: This answer will not work for library project (.aar)

Comment: What about `Build.gradle` I want to check if debug in gradle and not in java

Comment: @user924: That does not really work. `build.gradle` does not build Android apps. It builds a set of objects that describe how to build Android apps. So, `build.gradle` is used for every build type. At the time the `build.gradle` script is run, we are not yet building anything, and so there is no build type yet. That is why if you want different behavior for different build types you need to create custom tasks for *every* build type.

Answer (score 93):

Try the following:

```
boolean isDebuggable =  ( 0 != ( getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) );
```

Kotlin:

```
val isDebuggable = 0 != applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE
```

It is taken from bundells post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085644/how-to-check-if-apk-is-signed-or-debug-build)

Comment: This answer will work in all cases regardless of library project or application project.

Comment: What needs to be imported for `getApplicationInfo().flags` to work?

Comment: ok it just doesn't work in static context, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Comment: Without any imports:  if  (( getApplicationInfo().flags & android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) != 0). Nice if you are writing a library and don't want to constantly be modifying the file to reference your application's package. Does require context though.

Answer (score 76):

Yes, you will have no problems using:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   //It's not a release version.
}
```

Unless you are importing the wrong BuildConfig class. Make sure you are referencing your project's BuildConfig class, not from any of your dependency libraries.

[image]

Comment: "Unless you are importing the wrong BuildConfig class"... Yeah, very good point :D

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem in my project, somehow it was picking up library project's BuildConfig (which is always release mode until Android Studio 3 comes out)

Comment: I am getting an error undefined BuildConfig class in flutter.

Comment: What if, indeed, I'm in a different module that of the project? For example I make an SDK for other apps and I wish to check it out?

Answer (score 49):

Due to the mixed comments about `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, I used the following to disable crashlytics (and analytics) in debug mode :

**update /app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.awesome.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS', 'true'
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS', 'false'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

then, in your code you detect the `ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS` flag as follows:

```
    if (BuildConfig.ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS)
    {
        // enable crashlytics and answers (Crashlytics by default includes Answers)
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
```

use the same concept in your app and rename `ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS` to anything you want. I like this approach because I can see the flag in the configuration and I can control the flag.

Comment: You shouldn't call Crashlytics and Answers separately. Just use:

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
to include Crashlytics and Answers.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeBonnell, I made the code change to the example code

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from using BuildConfig.DEBUG - if you only set BuildConfig.ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS for your debug builds then BuildConfig.DEBUG and BuildConfig.ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS will always have the same value right?

Comment: I think dev's working on library projects had problems detecting debug/release builds using BuildConfig.DEBUG. There might have been an early Android Studio bug involved too...

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, you could differentiate using **BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;**

If you're running debug build
`BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("debug");` returns true. And for release build `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("release");` returns true.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Returns "release" whereas BuildConfig.DEBUG always returns `true`.

Comment: I am getting an error undefined BuildConfig class in flutter.

Comment: The only suggestion on this page that works 100% of the time! (hands clapping emoji)

Answer (score 15):

I am using this solution in case to find out that my app is running on debug version.

```
if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("debug")){
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer. It would be more helpful than just a piece of code.

Comment: I was using `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {} ` in a dependant gradle module which had (of course) NO REFERENCE to the app's build.gradle file - this caused debug mode to be recognised in a wrong way. `if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("Debug")){ }` FIXED the issue. Thanks

Comment: this is real answer, just change "Debug" to "debug"

Comment: I am getting an error undefined BuildConfig class in flutter.

Comment: @Kamlesh at the point of writing this answer Flutter was nowhere near our minds. Please be aware of that

Comment: If you are using Flutter for mobile app, you can use the constant kReleaseMode from package:flutter/foundation.dart

Comment: This is close, but don't hard code the name of the build variant in. See other answers below and just make sure you are importing the correct BuildConfig.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use this in the gradle/kts file , so that the BuildConfig file will be generated for you :

```
buildFeatures {
   buildConfig = true
}
```

Then, reach the field `BuildConfig.DEBUG` that belongs to the package name of your app.

Something similar to this which is less recommended (as it won't remove code when creating the release version) is to check if the app is debuggable:

```
val isDebuggable = context.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE != 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are importing the correct BuildConfig class
And yes, you will have no problems using:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   //It's not a release version.
}
```

Comment: Correct import is `<package_name>.BuildConfig`.

Comment: Not working for me. I am getting an error undefined BuildConfig class in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE could be all right. It comes from "ro.debuggable"

Comment: What if the release version was made to be debuggable, for some reason?

Comment: @androiddeveloper can release version be made debuggable?

Comment: @KhalidLakhani Pretty sure it can.

Comment: @KhalidLakhani Not only that, but a debug build can be non-debuggable

Comment: @androiddeveloper got it like buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false           
        }

Comment: @KhalidLakhani Indeed. Would be weird to have it for the debug build of not being debuggable, though :)