# Universal-Image-Loader | SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader, image-loading, sslhandshakeexception

I have a ListView with some content (TextViews, ImageView...) in the items. I'm using [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) by Nostra to load the images in the items but some of them fail to load. This is what do I get, when i call `Log.v(String.valueOf(failReason.getCause());` :

```
11-16 23:52:20.447: V/javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed(17467): failz
11-16 23:52:20.657: V/NativeCrypto(17467): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x15fd758: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
11-16 23:52:20.657: V/NativeCrypto(17467): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:762 0x4c2ed485:0x00000000)
11-16 23:52:21.207: V/NativeCrypto(17467): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1562468: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
11-16 23:52:21.207: V/NativeCrypto(17467): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:762 0x4c2ed485:0x00000000)
```

Don't you know, why is there this problem or how can I solve it?

This is one example image, which doesn't get loaded:

http://bigparty.cz/photos/headlinefoto/13.jpg

(I can attach a Log with the whole error - error which UIL **automatically** puts to Log)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm right you have to create a certificate, sign it and include it in your app. Or change the server configuration ([further information here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)).

Otherwise you can **trust every handshake** within your app. This is not the best approach, but really useful during implementation.

Include this class in your project

```
public class SSLCertificateHandler {

protected static final String TAG = "NukeSSLCerts";

/**
 * Enables https connections
 */
public static void nuke() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                return myTrustedAnchors;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

}
```

Extend your `Application`, and call the 'nuke' function in your `onCreate`

```
public class YOURApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //...

    // trust all SSL -> HTTPS connection
    SSLCertificateHandler.nuke();
}
```

I found this code in SO, but can't find the link at the moment....

Comment: I know this is useful during development. But don't even think about accepting all certificates once the app is live. This defeats the whole purpose of using HTTPS, you might as well use HTTP instead. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/4837230#4837230) (But ignore [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4837230/640731) answer)

Comment: It's possible to include a condition in the Java so `SSLCertificateHandler.nuke()` is only called for development builds - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23844716/1617737 .

Answer (score 2):

Might be you are missing intermediate CA certificate at your server end.

Try reading this

Most public CAs don't sign server certificates directly. Instead, they use their main CA certificate, referred to as the root CA, to sign intermediate CAs. They do this so the root CA can be stored offline to reduce risk of compromise. However, operating systems like Android typically trust only root CAs directly, which leaves a short gap of trust between the server certificate—signed by the intermediate CA—and the certificate verifier, which knows the root CA. To solve this, the server doesn't send the client only it's certificate during the SSL handshake, but a chain of certificates from the server CA through any intermediates necessary to reach a trusted root CA.

To see what this looks like in practice, here's the mail.google.com certificate chain as viewed by the openssl s_client command:

### $ openssl s_client -connect mail.google.com:443

Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mail.google.com
   i:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
 1 s:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA

### i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority

This shows that the server sends a certificate for mail.google.com issued by the Thawte SGC CA, which is an intermediate CA, and a second certificate for the Thawte SGC CA issued by a Verisign CA, which is the primary CA that's trusted by Android.

However, it is not uncommon to configure a server to not include the necessary intermediate CA. For example, here is a server that can cause an error in Android browsers and exceptions in Android apps:

### $ openssl s_client -connect egov.uscis.gov:443

Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=District Of Columbia/L=Washington/O=U.S. Department of Homeland Security/OU=United States Citizenship and Immigration Services/OU=Terms of use at www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05/CN=egov.uscis.gov

### i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3

*What is interesting to note here is that visiting this server in most desktop browsers does not cause an error like a completely unknown CA or self-signed server certificate would cause. This is because most desktop browsers cache trusted intermediate CAs over time. Once a browser has visited and learned about an intermediate CA from one site, it won't need to have the intermediate CA included in the certificate chain the next time.*

Some sites do this intentionally for secondary web servers used to serve resources. For example, they might have their main HTML page served by a server with a full certificate chain, but have servers for resources such as images, CSS, or JavaScript not include the CA, presumably to save bandwidth. Unfortunately, sometimes these servers might be providing a web service you are trying to call from your Android app, which is not as forgiving.

There are two approaches to solve this issue:

Configure the server to include the intermediate CA in the server chain. Most CAs provide documentation on how to do this for all common web servers. This is the only approach if you need the site to work with default Android browsers at least through Android 4.2.
Or, treat the intermediate CA like any other unknown CA, and create a TrustManager to trust it directly, as done in the previous two sections.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by longilong trusting all certificates is not the best approach. In fact it's a very bad approach in a production environment, since it basically nullifies the effect of SSL and makes you venerable to [Man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

The problem boils down to the [POODLE SSL3 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) which has made some (most?) service provider disable their SSLv3 support. This is bad news for us Android-developers because HttpConnection defaults to SSLv3 in Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 20.

There is an issue filed in the [Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78187) with more information and a solution consists of providing a custom SSLFactory which refuses to set SSLv3 as the only fallback protocol and here is the code from that very issue. I take no credit for this solution, but it is what we currently use for all versions before Lollipop.

```
/**
 * An {@link javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket} that doesn't allow {@code SSLv3} only connections
 * <p>fixes https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/386</p>
 */
private static class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
    super(delegate);

    String canonicalName = delegate.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    if (!canonicalName.equals("org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl")){
        // try replicate the code from HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket()
        try {
            Method msetUseSessionTickets = delegate.getClass().getMethod("setUseSessionTickets", boolean.class);
            if (null != msetUseSessionTickets) {
                msetUseSessionTickets.invoke(delegate, true);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ignored) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
    if (protocols != null && protocols.length == 1 && "SSLv3".equals(protocols[0])) {
        // no way jose
        // see issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78187
        List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getEnabledProtocols()));
        if (enabledProtocols.size() > 1) {
            enabledProtocols.remove("SSLv3");
        } else {
            LogManager.getLogger().w("SSL stuck with protocol available for " + String.valueOf(enabledProtocols));
        }
        protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
    }
    super.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
}
}


/**
 * {@link javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory} that doesn't allow {@code SSLv3} only connections
 */
private static class NoSSLv3Factory extends SSLSocketFactory {
private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

private NoSSLv3Factory() {
    this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

private static Socket makeSocketSafe(Socket socket) {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
        socket = new NoSSLv3SSLSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
    }
    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}
}

static {
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new NoSSLv3Factory());
}
```

Comment: this helped me a lot. I hope that it will also help the others. thank you