# Universal Image Loader API level 17 below ssl Handshake error why? how to resolve this issue

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

```
E/ImageLoader: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb80a6f70: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
               error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x82ba9990:0x00000000)
               javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb80a6f70: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
               error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x82ba9990:0x00000000)
                   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
                   at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
                   at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
                   at com.credihealth.android.utilities.AuthImageDownloader.getStream(AuthImageDownloader.java:105)
                   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
                   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
                   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
                   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb80a6f70: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
               error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x82ba9990:0x00000000)
                   at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
                    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Did you look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963154/universal-image-loader-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed

Comment: that solution already implemented before but now it's again not working