# SSL Handshake Exception Occurs when i load Image with Imageloader

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, universal-image-loader

First of all i want to say that i am new on stackoverflow and also fresher in Android,so if i do any mistake so please suggest me something best and help me to be best programmer.

So my question is defined in title but i can explain more at here.

I am using ImageLoader and i am loading image from an URL 
 **https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/aolmislogs/buyer/payment_proof/1.jpg**

but in my RecyclerView image is not showing and SSL Handshake Exception occurs.

When I remove 's' from https and loading image from an URL 
 **http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/aolmislogs/buyer/payment_proof/1.jpg**

it's working.

I want to know why this happening and what is the solution if I want to use URL with 'https://'.How can I fix this Exception,please give me best solution of this Exception.

> http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/aolmislogs/buyer/payment_proof/2.jpg
>   08-17 12:57:15.325 2095-2095/com.kmsg.aolmis.buyer W/ImageLoader: Try
>   to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before.
>   To re-init ImageLoader with new configuration call
>   ImageLoader.destroy() at first. 08-17 12:57:15.334
>   2095-2095/com.kmsg.aolmis.buyer E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with
>   no current context (logged once per thread) 08-17 12:57:15.675
>   2095-2911/com.kmsg.aolmis.buyer E/ImageLoader:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
>           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
>           at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
>           at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
>        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304) 
>           at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
>           at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
>   Method) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)  08-17 12:57:15.951 2095-2911/com.kmsg.aolmis.buyer E/ImageLoader:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
>           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:98)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:74)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:265)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:238)
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
>           at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
>           at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:98) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:74) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:265) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:238) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
>        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304) 
>           at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
>           at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
>   Method) 
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105) 
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:98) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:74) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:265) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:238) 
>           at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

Comment: is the time and date on your device correct?

Comment: yeah, time and date is correct in my device...but how can effect this by time and date.

Comment: ssl certificate is valid for certain time.

Comment: ok,but time and date is correct in my device. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: are there any other error details? Like why the handshake failed?

Comment: I edited all details which exceptions are occuring... @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: which Android version are you checking on?

Comment: its 3.1.4 @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: did you see this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963154/universal-image-loader-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed

Answer (score 0):

That server is not having `SSL`, that's why you need to use `http` protocol, not `https`

**Update**

After a better look at your links, i found that you are missing a dash

From

https://s3.ap-south1.amazonaws.com/...

to

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/...

Your url is working fine now: https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/aolmislogs/buyer/payment_proof/1.jpg

Comment: what should i do then...??

Comment: sorry but it was not correct answer...i wrote wrong at here but not in my code i checked at there...and now i updated also here which i wrote wrong...it was my mistake so sorry but it was not correct answer...