# Define classes for debug builds in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Where should I declare a class that only must be compiled for the debug variant of an app in Android Studio?

What I want to make is to save some faked responses from a web service, stripping it from the release version to ensure never ship that code:

```
 public static DebugFakeResponses{
     public static final String RESPONSE_SERVER_IN_MAINTENTANTE
                               ="{\"error\":\"In Maintentance\"}";
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, you can exclude something from compiling in debug mode without using a build system. But you could simply check, if you're in debug mode and execute the code only in this case:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something for a debug build
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/android-detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode)