# What is the compiler symbol for debugging enabled?

Tags: android, android-studio

At one point, I ran across some Android documentation that recommended writing debug code like this:

if (someSymbol) then
{
   .. debug code like log
}

where someSymbol was automatically set by the compiler to either true (for debug) or false (for release). Then the debug code is optimized out in the release version.

But I didn't write it down, and now I can't find it.

What is that symbol?

Comment: Try "if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {...}" according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/android-detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode.

Answer (score 0):

(Just so this shows up as answered)

The symbol is BuildConfig.DEBUG