# How to tell if you are running in "Release Mode" at runtime

Tags: android, mobile, react-native

Is there a way to tell if the Android React-Native app is in "release mode" at runtime?

Is there perhaps a well to tell if the app has been signed?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode-in-android) you can find an answer.

Comment: @mpostal I think he wants to know how to do it on React?

Comment: @Bhargav Correct, this a a React Native question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if `__DEV__` is true or false

```
if (__DEV__) {
  // then development mode
} else {
  // release mode
}
```