# how can i make a label invisible at release build

Tags: android, listview, visibility, release-builds, debug-build

I want to hide a listview item on release build but make it visible on debug build. I searched it on internet but I can't find anything about it. Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, you can create build flavors in your gradle file which then you can you use in an if statement to set the visibility.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read first in the help center, how to ask a good question on this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. So we can better unterstand your question and can help you with your problems.

Comment: Why don't you set the visibility to invisible?

Comment: 1. You can use flavor and have different layout for debug and release. 2. You can use  BuildConfig.DEBUG flag in if else statements.

Comment: BuildConfig.DEBUG worked. thanks

Answer (score 5):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode-in-android), there is an option to detect if an app is in debug or release mode:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   lbl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   lbl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Then you simply set the visibility based on the condition to visible or invisible.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks...