# Determine build variant of app from inside an SDK library code

Tags: android, sdk, variant, buildconfig

**My question:**
How to get the build variant of an app hosting my AAR library code?

**Background:**
 - A method that returns an apps build variant should use:
BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE

- I'm writing an SDK library. I want to know the build variant of the application hosting my library (mainly to avoid running my code in release variant).
- BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE is package dependant, I don't know the package of the app hosting me and BuildConfig has no getter. I can't ask for the host app's BuildConfig.

Comment: your idea likely will fail. Why? `release` is just a name, which can be totally **anything**. For example I don't use the `release` build type for some of my projects. I call them `release<Environment>`. Even more - you can name the build type `debug`, but configure it as release. So using build type to limit production usage of your lib is not going to work

Comment: As alternative, you may try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844693/1568530