# Where are build types of the app defined?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

1. I know we can edit build types in Android Studio:

   [image: Build Types]
2. I know we can edit each build type setting in gradle:

   ```
   android {
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled true
           }
       }
   ```
3. I know we can detect build types in code. [How do I detect if I am in release or debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/how-do-i-detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode)

But where actually are the build types defined? Let say I want to commit it to git. What should I do to keep build types of the project consistent?

Comment: BuildConfig class gets generated inside following path *"app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/yourBuildType/yourPackageName/BuildConfig.java"*

Comment: You should not make it consistent. because, it's generated class and it should be get generated upon every successful clean/re build.

Comment: @JeelVankhede 1. So the BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE in code comes from what Android Studio injected when we run a build? 2. As a developer, we should rely on the buildTypes specified in build.gradle to config our Android Studio to match them. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, we can totally rely on BuildConfig class. But just to make you clear, Android studio doesn't inject anything but it's compiler which generates such classes.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Got it! I think this is a valid answer. Could you sum it and post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where actually are the build types defined?

Basically, `BuildConfig` is the auto-generated class that resides under path :

*app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/yourBuildType/yourPackageName/BuildConfig.java*.

This class holds variables provided by `buildTypes {}` block from app level **build.gradle** file. So, on every clean & rebuild of project, **Gradle** auto generates `BuildConfig` class that can be used in further **Android development environment**.

---

I.e. **`BuildConfig.DEBUG`** is the default variable that we can use in our application code to determine it's **`buildType`**.

We can provide our own fields through `buildType` from **build.gradle** file like following:

```
android {
. . .
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "SOME_VARIABLE", '"This string value is from build config class"'
        }
    }
. . .
}
```