# Two questions about providing instance of HttpLoggingInterceptor for OkHttpClient in Dagger 2 module

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp, retrofit2.6

I am developing an Android project with Kotlin and Dagger 2.  I have a `NetworkModule` it is supposed to provide a singleton instance of Retrofit. in which I define all those provider functions.

All code snippet below are inside `NetworkModule` :

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {
   ...
}
```

**My 1st question:**

I want to provide a singleton of `HttpLoggingInterceptor` for `OkHttpClient`. Here is what I tried:

```
@Provides
internal fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): Interceptor {
    // compiler error: Unresolved reference 'setLevel', unresolved reference 'Level'
    return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
}
```

But I get a compilation error: `Unresolved reference 'setLevel'` and `Unresolved reference 'Level'`, How to get rid of it?

**My 2nd question:**

I define my OkHttpClient provider function as:

```
@Provides
internal fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: Interceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                        ...
                        .build()
}
```

How can I make it so that only `addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)` when it is in the debug model, whereas in release mode not add the  `HttpLoggingInterceptor` in the above provider function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, are you sure you have the right dependencies?

Or since you are in Kotlin, try it like this:

```
@JvmStatic
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    return httpLoggingInterceptor
}
```

For you second question:

> How can I make it so that only addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor) when
>   it is in the debug model, whereas in release mode not add the
>   HttpLoggingInterceptor in the above provider function?

```
@Provides
@JvmStatic
@Singleton
fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptor: Interceptor): OkHttpClient{
 val okhttpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder() //and every other method after it except build() would return a Builder (Builder pattern)
 if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
  okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
 }
 return okHttpBuilder.build()
}
```

Notice the `@JvmStatic` and `@Singleton` annotations since you are using Singletons. One is for the JVM and the other for scoping.

Comment: I checked the `@JvmStatic` definition https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html  , but why do we need it here if it is for static getter and setter of element, here what kind of static getter and setter are generated under the hood?

Comment: What dependency should I have for `HttpLoggingInterceptor` ? I still get the same error.

Comment: `com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1`

Comment: Thanks. Are you able also give an answer to my 1st question in my above comment?  And I have another issue which I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488983/why-i-still-get-cannot-inline-bytecode-built-with-jvm-target-1-8-into-bytecode

Comment: I'm not sure if you should use `internal` but however just place annotations just as I describe in my answer `@Provides` `@Singleton` `@JVMStatic`

Answer (score 0):

For setting the logger only in DEBUG builds you have two options

1. Use the NONE level based on Build.DEBUG

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844716/1542667

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor l = ...;

if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    l.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
}
```

2. Use Dagger optional/nullable to avoid setting the interceptor

https://medium.com/@birajdpatel/avoid-nullable-dependencies-in-dagger2-with-bindsoptionalof-c3ad8a8fde2c