# Why I still get "Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6"

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an Android project with Kotlin and Dagger 2. I have a `NetworkModule` it is supposed to provide a singleton instance of Retrofit. In which I define all those provider functions.

All code snippet below are inside `NetworkModule` :

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {
   ...
}
```

I want to provide `HttpRequestInterceptor` , this is what I tried:

```
@Provides
@JvmStatic
internal fun provideHttpRequestInterceptor(): Interceptor {
    // compiler error: Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into 
    // bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6, 
    // please specify proper '-jvm-target' option

    return Interceptor { chain ->
        val original = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        val request = requestBuilder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

But the above code always give me this compiler error: `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6, please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`

In my `build.gradle` I have specified:

```
android {
   ...
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

I have two questions now:

1. What is built with jvm 1.6 and 1.8 respectively? How this could happen (please use example to explain) ?
2. As you can see in my build.gradle I already declared build target is JVM 1.8. Why I still get this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246275/4694013

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add `kotlinOptions` and set `jvmTarget` to 1.8 in your `build.gradle` file to resolve the problem

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Could you please also give an answer for my 1st question?

Comment: *Calls to static methods in Java interfaces are prohibited in JVM target 1.6*. So you can't use it in 1.6. You have to use 1.8.

Comment: Thanks, could you please also take a look at my another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489252/the-annotation-for-provider-function-of-dagger-module-class

Comment: I put this inside "android" in the app build.gradle.

Comment: I have this set in Android Studio's settings, but I'm still getting the error. I've rebuilt and restarted... no dice.

Comment: @Oscar, This is not related to *Android Studio's settings*. You have to add this inside **APP** level `build.gradle` file

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Thanks, but then what’s the meaning of the “Target JVM version” in Android’s Kotlin compiler settings?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman It turns out that this is a bug in Android Studio, which is being addressed.

Comment: An explanation, or at least a lead to any theoretical course would have been appreciated.

Comment: I have this in my project and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above. I had to go to editor settings in android studio and manually change the kotlin compiler version

[image]

Comment: but don't forget restart IDEA after the change

Comment: That + invalidate caches solved the problem for me.