# The annotation for provider function of dagger module class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an Android project with Kotlin and Dagger 2. I have a `NetworkModule` in which I define some provider functions.

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {
   @Provides
   @JvmStatic  // Here uses @JvmStatic
   internal fun provideSomething(): Something {
      ...
   }
}
```

I see some people use kotlin `@JvmStatic` and some use dagger's `@Reusable` to annotate the provider function:

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {
   @Provides
   @Reusable  // Here uses @Reusable
   internal fun provideSomething(): Something {
      ...
   }
}
```

And..some people use both:

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {
   @Provides
   @JvmStatic // Here use both @JvmStatic
   @Reusable  // and uses @Reusable
   internal fun provideSomething(): Something {
      ...
   }
}
```

I get confused. My two questions are:

1. What is the motivation to annotate either `@JvmStatic` and/or `@Reusable` ? What's the reason behind or what is the benefit doing so?
2. Which one is better to use `@JvmStatic` or `@Reusable` ? Or either one is fine? Or should I use both, if so what is the reason to use both then?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your module as a Kotlin object, `@JvmStatic` was required. That limitation was removed with [dagger 2.25](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.25.2) You can also check [this issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900) for more info.

If you use Dagger 2.25 or newer there is no reason to use `@JvmStatic` anymore.

From the `@Reusable` docs:

> A scope that indicates that the object returned by a binding may be (but might not be) reused.
>
> {@code @Reusable} is useful when you want to limit the number of provisions of a type, but there is no specific lifetime over which there must be only one instance.

If you inject the same thing in multiple places, and having the same instance is not a problem, this can help not to create a new object for each usage.

`@JvmStatic` and `@Reusable` are not related to each other, depending on your need you can use one, the other or both of them.