# how to set value in my class varible when change Android Debug/Release

Tags: java, android, debugging, gradle, release

i want to change isDebug variable when i change built type from debug/relese

**here is simple class where i want set true/false isDebug**

```
    public class StartConfig {
    public static boolean isDebug;
    }
```

**here is my build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            StartConfig.isDebug = false // here i want to set variable
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug 
            StartConfig.isDebug = true // here i want to set variable
            minifyEnabled false
        }

    }
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing reverse. just take a look to this link:

[How do I detect if I am in release or debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/how-do-i-detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode/23844716)

This is simple easy and no definition required by you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use BuildConfig.DEBUG in your java code. It returns a boolean value