# android rtl issue using v17 version layout

Tags: android, android-support-library, right-to-left

I'm trying to support rtl view in a layout that has an imageView and textView (so in rtl devices the image will be at the right side of the text, see pic below)

in order to accomplish that I:

- created v17 layout (see below).
- added `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the manifest

the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/asked_by_container"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_imageview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/question_profile_icon_corner_radius"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/anonprofile01" />

    <com.theapp.widget.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/asked_textview"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_imageview"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:ttf_name="fonts/merriweather_sans/MerriweatherSans-Regular.otf"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.theapp.widget.CustomTextView
    android:layout_below="@id/asked_by_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/question_textview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:ttf_name="fonts/merriweather_sans/MerriweatherSans-Regular.otf"/>
```

the preview shows that it should work:
[android studio regular and rtl preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPHID.png)

To be sure I added `rootView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);` in the adapter holding the RelativeLayout.

It didnt work so I made sure the app is actually using the v17 version (by adding a dummy button in the v17 version).. still not working.. any help?

I also checked [Force RTL layout direction not working for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356178/force-rtl-layout-direction-not-working-for-app) but it wasn't useful to me..

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer I'm confronting a similar issue.

Comment: no. I just didn't have so much time to solve this, so I just done it programmatically. I used this func:

    `public static boolean isRTL(Context ctx) {
        Configuration config = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration();
        return config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Once set `layoutDirection` opposite to the `textDirection`

and once set `layoutDirection` same as the `textDirection`

to see which one could help you in your situation.