# Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; Warning in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, eclipse-adt

After updating my ADT plugin to version 17 I'm getting a warning massage saying

> Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

There wasn't such message before the update.

How can I avoid this warning message ?

Comment: Where are these Google gurus? I want to know this too

Comment: @Bostone, See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23986724/632951

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yup, just noticed this too. I removed the debuggable attribute from the manifest, and I can now both run the app in debug mode and export it to a market-ready APK file without changing any code.

Slick!

Full explanation here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580630/682754

Comment: I'm curious too how it works. So does that means I don't need to remove any "Log.d()" from my code when publishing released apk?

Answer (score 17):

Ran into this myself today and was frustrated with the accepted answer; I don't want to trust Eclipse to "do the right thing" when it so often doesn't.

The answer to the question asked is to go to Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking or Project Properties->Android Lint Preferences and change the severity of the warning.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone the preference your looking for is called'HardcodedDebugMode' under the 'Security' heading. This worked for me. Thanks