# Android Error :Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

Tags: android-manifest

I wanted to debug the the app i am developing and it is my first app. I followed a video where it showed to set debuggable to true in androidmanifest file and i did so . I am getting this particular error in that androidmanifest.xml file at line of code `android:debuggable= "true"` Error is

> Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: You can totally refer this for this issue: [Debuggable issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580595/what-would-happen-if-android-app-is-released-with-debuggable-on/4580630#4580630

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23986724/632951

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; Warning in Android Manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868241/avoid-hardcoding-the-debug-mode-warning-in-android-manifest)

Answer (score 3):

remove this line `android:debuggable= "true">`

or

Go to Tools > Build Clean to solve your problem