# Android package not debuggable

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I explicitly set my app debuggable to true in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and deployed it to my device through `eclipse`, but I still get the

```
run-as: Package 'com.mypackage' is not debuggable
```

when I run the command:

```
adb -d shell 'run-as com.mypackage cat /data/data/com.mypackage/databases/mydb.db > /sdcard/mydb.db'
```

What do I need to change to be able to debug my application?

Comment: Did you build / export a release version? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580595/what-would-happen-if-android-app-is-released-with-debuggable-on

Comment: no I am not making a release build.

Comment: I am having a similar problem but more curious about other aspect of the issue. I have my device logs in _data/data/package-name_ which I need for investigation. I can access this file on _device-1_ and cannot on _device-2_ even though I am using the same apk for both. In the device file explorer it shows `run-as package not debuggable` for _device-2_. It makes me think we can access this area by somehow changing device settings. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Are you using `release apk` or `debug apk` for testing? If you use release version of the `apk` you wouldn't get the access. I would suggest you to build the application directly from Android Studio (remember that your Build Variant must be `debug` in Android Studio) and try using the command `run-as "your.package.name"`

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure you built with and `AndroidManifest.xml` with `debuggable=true`, then uninstalling the package may work (caution: this will also wipe this apps' data).

```
adb uninstall your.package.name
```

It seems that AndroidManifest.xml is sticky, for reasons I don't fully understand.  I would encounter this case when I had a non-debug APK as my initial install, and then sideload a debuggable APK later.

Comment: Hi, sorry for this off topic comment. I saw your profile pic on mathematics chatroom (a flying sheep? :D)  May I know where is it from?

Comment: Hi, I changed my profile, but it is a tardigrade - a micro animal also known as a 'water bear' that can survive the vacuum of space for a little while.

Answer (score 1):

Like @ prudhvi said, this an be solved by settings build variant to debug

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Try changing your package name to `com.my.pack.age` because there seems to be an issue with packages names less than 4 levels. Also make sure that the package is mentioned in `/data/system/packages.list`. Information taken from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13965).