# Android error when I set android:debuggable = "false" or "true"

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-debug

Please help me to solve this error.

When I put debuggable, the error appear like this

"Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one".

So i don't know what to do....
Anyone can help me.
Thank you

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580595/what-would-happen-if-android-app-is-released-with-debuggable-on/4580630#4580630

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **NOT** an error, merely a warning. You can still compile, debug & run your application on emulators / devices. When you *export* your application to create a release build, by default this APK is **NOT** debuggable, since this APK will be released to users, but the APK you are currently building is debugabble by default, so if you wish you can remove the `android:debuggable` tag.

**References:**

**1.** [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)

In the above link go to `SDK Tools, Revision 8` and there see `General Notes`.

**2.** [Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up)

Comment: but this shows as an error with red underline can't save or run at all

Comment: @user3434063: go to `Project` and select `Clean` and clean your project. Then, if it does not get built automatically, right click on your project in the package explorer and select `Build Project`

Comment: thanks ... hope your workflow is going well now ... :)