# Android Studio - run application on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run the application on my Sony Xperia but it doesn't work. I have followed the steps on http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

1. I have enabled USB debugging on my device
2. I have installed the drivers using the Sony PC Companion
   (everything well so far as when I try to run it, Android Studio finally recognizes my mobile as a device)
3. The step I think I am doing wrong is making my application "debuggable" in the build.gradle file

   I have pasted the code in the build.gradle(Module:app)

   android {
       buildTypes {
           debug {
               debuggable true
           }
        }
     }

But when I run it I get the following error:

> Unexpected Error Local path doesn't exist. Local path doesn't exist.
>   The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.

Any ideas/tips how I can solve this?

Comment: have u tried to remove the debuggable option?

Comment: look at this question n se if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952140/android-how-do-i-mark-my-app-as-debuggable

Comment: You already asked this question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875902/android-studio-run-on-device/28877054#28877054

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what OS you have but if you have Windows 7, I would recommend doing the following:

- Connect your cellphone to your computer
- Right click on your `My Computer` and go to `Properties` then `Device Manager`
- Look for your device **(It may be under Other Devices or under a separate branch maybe Sony)**
- When you find the device, right click on it and select uninstall
- In the meantime, you can go to this [link](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver) and download Universal Windows ADB Driver **(This one worked for me)** or if you want to use the one you downloaded from SDK Manager, just go to: `C:/Users/(Username)/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/usb_driver`
- When you finish uninstalling the driver unplug it and plug it back in so the computer can recognize the device.
- When the computer recognize it, go back into device manager and look for the device that has an yellow exclamation point.
- Right click on the device with the yellow exclamation point and click `Update Driver Software...`
- When the update driver window shows up, click `Browse my computer for driver software`
- **If you downloaded and installed the Universal ADB, the you must direct the path to** `C:/Program Files (x86)/ClockworkMod/Universal Adb Driver/usb_driver` **if not then to the other path which is the one I mentioned above**
- Wait until installation finish then restart the computer **(Optional)** then give it a try.